# "SAVE PERMALINKS" does more than FLUSH_REWRITE_RULES?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I noticed many cases, when i register some custom rules or etc, and next to it, do `flush_rewrite_rules()` (i know, after that i need to re-load page once again to start the changed rules), however new rules doesnt work.

I got to "permalinks" page, re-save permalinks (without any change on that page), and voila - my functions start to work..

I think, saving permalinks do more than `flush_rewrite_rules()` and is there any function available to do that programatically?

Comment: Are these internal rules or external? Can you show an example of how you are adding rules and flushing them that gives you this result? You probably have an order issue.

Comment: @Milo thanks, it's strange, but seemed that after flush_rewrite_rules, if you `exit`, then rules doesnt change ( try to `exit` with outputting `get_option('rewrite_rules')` after flushing rules. you see, the value is not changed on next pageloads even, until you allow at least one full-load of wp)

Comment: You can look at the source for the `options-permalink.php` file, it doesn't do anything else other than call `flush_rewrite_rules()`. You actually don't even have to click save, it flushes rules just by loading that page.

Comment: @Milo ouh, i didnt know that (just loading that page), thanks!